# Why google maps is opened wrong?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I use Angular Google Maps.
The map works when is loaded HTML in `ng-view` from AJAX with controller `MapController`, that displays map.
I see [image: wrong format map], how I can fix it? May be set timeout?

**CSS:**

```
#map_canvas {
    border: 2px solid #7da9cd;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
   position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="MapController">
   // Angular JS directives
</div>
```

Comment: have you set height of elements? create demo that replicates this including the css you are using

Comment: Okay. Now will update question

Comment: there's another angular map class also that needs height also...inspect the live html. Class is `angular-google-map`

Comment: What do you mean? For what class to set `height`?

Comment: inspect the live html in browser dev tools will see that class I mentioned that is outside the `angular-google-map-container` class. It needs height also

Comment: I tried: `#map_canvas .angular-google-map {
    height: 300px;
}` Does not help, also for `angular-google-map-container`

Comment: compare your live html to a working demo. Also is height set on `ng-view`? Again...create demo that replicates problem

Comment: Seems problem is in another. When I open dev tools, map is rebuild right automaticly

Comment: worst case can get the map object itself (per docs) and call google maps resize method on it. Also I think there is a `refresh` attribute. Can't help much more without code and demo

Comment: Example: `http://plnkr.co/edit/HgQafwCI9p0NXyxtKWVf?p=preview`

Comment: works fine for me in 2 browsers but it also isn't inside ng-view

Comment: It works, but this is example witout error

Comment: I think I was have this problem if I open (initialize) the gmap window after render the page, if you need dynamically open on popup or js open windows where is your gmap. you can fix that if you again initialize the param.. Hope help.